# Plot specific rows of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a pandas dataframe with three columns and I am plotting each column separately using the following code:

```
data.plot(y='value')
```

Which generates a figure like this one:

[image]

What I need is a subset of these values and not all of them. For example, I want to plot values at rows 500 to 1000 and not from 0 to 3500. Any idea how I can tell the plot function to only pick those?

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to slice your df:

```
data.iloc[499:999].plot(y='value')
```

this will slice from row 500 up to but not including row 1000

Example:

```
In [35]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2), columns=list('ab'))
df.iloc[2:6]

Out[35]:
          a         b
2  0.672884  0.202798
3  0.514998  1.744821
4 -1.982109 -0.770861
5  1.364567  0.341882

df.iloc[2:6].plot(y='b')
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image]In case you have two dataframes say, *'tst'* and *'ptst'* and want to display only certain values of both **(same range in both)** on the same graph. Following will help:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plts

plts.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plts.plot(tst['Price'])
plts.plot(ptst['Price'])
```

Comment: How does it plot a certain number of rows ?